# Having no backup, how to recover Viber messages after reinstalling Viber?

Tags: data-recovery, viber-messenger

I want to recover my Viber messages. By mistake, I deleted Viber from my phone and I didn't do a backup.

Is there a way to get the messages back?

Answer (score 0):

Viber doesn’t provide any backup of the chat history from their servers. But, you can restore deleted Viber messages with [Free Android Data Recovery](https://www.gihosoft.com/android-data-recovery-free.html), It can recover deleted Viber messages on any Android device.

**P.S:** you should be using Viber on the phone where it was installed on.